# After a non-final rejection how can I respond with a traversal?

Tags: response, non-final

So far I've always responded to non-final rejections with an amendment and arguments/remarks, so I've filed "Amendment/Req. Reconsideration-After Non-Final Reject" together with "Claims" and "Applicant Arguments/Remarks Made In An Amendment".

This time I am not supplying any amendments. What eFS drop-down options should I be selecting?

Comment: Whether any amendment is involved or not response is to be made under heading  "Amendment/Req. Reconsideration-After Non-Final Reject" as response to non-final rejection Office Action of USPTO and for that matter after final rejection too because the bottom line is applicant's response is "request for reconsideration". Of course the response is important for future course of action such as appeal.

Comment: Thanks. So the cover page, as usual, is as usual. But what category do the argument pages go under, "Request for reconsideration"? Or does the whole response go under "Amendment/Req. Reconsideration-After Non-Final Reject"?

Comment: Needs to mention on cover page (at the bottom) Remarks/Arguments  -  begins at page 2 of this paper. Then as usual, on page 2, Page Heading (Remarks/Arguments). First sub-heading - Asserted Subject Matter, Second Sub-heading (next paragraph) - Arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it is the same selection- "Amendment/Req. Reconsideration-After Non-Final Reject" and  "Applicant Arguments/Remarks Made In An Amendment".

The second choice can read as "Applicant arguments. Or Applicant remarks made in an amendment."